# Does this sentence wish an increase in the age of retirement or a decrease in it?

Tags: sentence-meaning, discourse-context

Does this sentence:

> Some experts regard the retirement age of 65 as an anachronism at a
>   time when people in the developed world have much longer life
>   expectancies than previously.

wish an increase in the age of retirement or a decrease in it?

Comment: Suppose your life expectancy is 70. If you retire at the standard age of 65, you retire when your life is 92.8% (65/70) over. if your life expectancy is 80, and you should retire when 92.8% of your life is over, then you should retire when you're a bit over 74. Does that help or hurt?

Comment: yeah, that was A HELP! thanks . . . @user105719

Answer (score 2):

The sentence suggests that some experts find the retirement age of 65 early considering the increased life expectancy. However, the sentence in itself does not necessarily suggest that the author wishes for a later retirement age. It is merely stating the opinion of some experts.